# Invariant measure of a subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be an abelian group with a $G$-invariant metric $d$. Let $H$ be a countable dense subgroup of $G$. Let $\mu$ be a non-atomic $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $G$ that is $H$-invariant. Must it be $G$-invariant?

EDIT: Sorry, this was not stated correctly. I have corrected the question (added the word "non-atomic"). As stated in the answer, this is not true for $\mu$ to be any measure for you can just place an atom on every element of $H$. I'm curious if there are any non-locally finite (and non-atomic) examples.

Comment: It's not true, let $\mu$ be counting measure on $H$.  However, if $\mu$ is a finite measure then it should be true.

Comment: @NateEldredge How does that work for a dense cyclic subgroup of the circle? I don't see why the counting measure on that subgroup extends to a sigma-finite measure on the Borel sigma-algebra of the circle

Comment: Do you require $\mu$ to be positive or can it be a signed measure? Also, is the locally compact abelian case good enough for you, or are your interested in more general metric abelian groups?

Comment: @YemonChoi: It just extends in the trivial way. Pushforward under the inclusion map, if you like. So $\mu(A) = \#(A \cap H)$ for any $A \subset G$,  or, $\mu = \sum_{h \in H} \delta_h$.  It's true that it's not a very interesting measure, since every open set has measure $\infty$, but it is certainly $H$-invariant and $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Maybe the measure was supposed to be Radon?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, that's the definition I thought you meant but I was being a bit dense (no pun intended) on seeing why it was sigma-finite, indeed somehow in my head I was imposing some regularity assumption without realising it

Comment: If the group $G$ is locally compact and the measure is Radon, then the claim is true as the measure is determined by its integrals of compactly supported continuous functions.

Comment: It is generally inappropriate to edit a question to invalidate [existing answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380685), especially since the answer also poses and addresses a more reasonable version of the question.    It _is_ a good idea to edit the question with clarifying remarks, but it should be indicated that they were not in the original version.

Comment: @Zero, I'm sorry to be ([har har](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380664/invariant-measure-of-a-subgroup#comment967035_380664), or perhaps I mean Haar Haar) dense, but is the [idea](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380664/invariant-measure-of-a-subgroup#comment967052_380664) to view a $G$-translate of $f \in \operatorname C_c(G)$ as a limit of $H$-translates of $f$, use the fact that each $H$-translate has the same integral as $f$, and conclude?

Answer (score 6):

It's not true as stated.  You can take $\mu$ to be counting measure on
$H$, i.e. $\mu(A) = \#(A \cap H)$.  This is trivially $H$-invariant
and $\sigma$-finite (the countably many points of $H$ each have finite
measure, and the rest of $G$ has measure zero), but it is not
$G$-invariant.

For a non-atomic example, take for instance $G = \mathbb{R}^2$, $H = \mathbb{Q}^2$, and $\mu$ the product of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with counting measure on $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $\int f\,d\mu = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  f(x, q)\,dx$.

However, if you suppose $\mu$ is Radon, then it's true.  Let $g \in G$
be arbitrary and let $K \subset G$ be an arbitrary compact set.  Let
$\epsilon > 0$, and let $h_n$ be a sequence in $H$ which converges to
$g$.  Since $\mu$ is Radon we can find an open set $U \supset K$ such
that $\mu(U) \le \mu(K) + \epsilon$.  Then for sufficiently large $n$,
we have $K + (g - h_n) \subset U$ as well.  (If not, then passing to a subsequence we can find for each $n$ some $x_n \in K$ for which $x_n + g - h_n \notin U$.  By compactness, passing to a further subsequence, $x_n$ converges to some $x \in K$.  Then $x_n + g - h_n \to x$ which is absurd because $x \in K \subset U$.)

Thus $$\mu(K+g) =
\mu(K+(g-h_n)) \le \mu(U) \le \mu(K) + \epsilon.$$  Since $\epsilon$
was arbitrary we have $\mu(K+g) \le \mu(K)$, and the reverse
inequality follows by symmetry.  Using again the fact that $\mu$ is
Radon, every Borel set can be approximated in measure from within by
compact sets, and so this suffices to conclude that $\mu$ is
$G$-invariant.

I think this is true, with much the same proof, for any topological group $G$ (not necessarily abelian or metrizable or locally compact) and any dense subgroup $H$ (not necessarily countable).  If $G$ is not abelian then it says that if $\mu$ is  invariant under left (respectively, right) multiplication by $H$, then $\mu$ is left (right) invariant. If $G$ should fail to be first countable you can replace the sequence $h_n$ in the above argument with a net.

Comment: Argument for $K + (g - h_n) \subseteq U$ for people who like to cover their compact sets rather than pass to subnets:  cover $K$ by open sets $U_x \subseteq U$ about each point $x \in K$, use continuity to shrink to $x \in V_x \subseteq U_x$ with $V_x + V_x - x \subseteq U_x$, pass to a finite sub-cover $(V_{x_i})_{i = 1}^n$, and put $V = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n (V_{x_i} - x_i)$.  Then $K + V \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^n V_{x_i} + V_{x_i} - x_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^n U_{x_i} \subseteq U$.